# Keeping devise flash message only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Hello i have a quick question. I get 2 flash messages, the devise one and the scaffolded one. How can i just have the Devise message in the beautiful flash box only?

Here is my code for creating Products:

```
def create
    @product = current_user.products.build(params[:product])
    @product.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@product, :notice => 'Product was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @product, :status => :created, :location => @product }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @product.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**products/show.html.erb:**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p><b>Name:</b><%= @product.name %> </p>
<p><b>Date:</b><%= @product.date %></p>
<p><b>Price:</b><%= number_to_currency(@product.price) %></p>
<p><b>User:</b><%= @product.user_id %></p>
<p><b>Latitude:</b><%= @product.latitude %></p>
<p><b>Longitude:</b><%= @product.longitude %></p>
<p><b>Tags:</b> <%= @product.tag_list %></p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(@product) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', products_path %>
```

Thank you!

Comment: How are you getting two flash messages. Please post the views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a 'notice' in your application.html.erb as well?

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
```

It may be best to put your notice & alert in there, instead of in all of your views anyway. Always good to refactor.

Comment: I have <%- flash.each do |name, msg| -%>
  <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" if msg.is_a?(String) %>
  <%- end -%> in my application.html.erb if that helps any.

Comment: I don't know a ton about flash messages, but it looks to me like you are putting the flash message in your application twice. Once from the application.html.erb and once in your products/show.html. Hence the duplication. Does this make sense?

Comment: If you remove it from your products/show.html.erb, I believe you should still see your flash message. I think :)

Answer (score 1):

I think devise is sending a flash measage because of the way you are building a product. Instead you might try this:

```
def create
    @product = Product.new(params[:product])
    @product.user = current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@product, :notice => 'Product was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @product, :status => :created, :location => @product }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @product.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: I changed it but still not luck. I still get two "Product was successfully created", one in the green flash box and another below it in plain text.

Comment: You have two flash notices. Check all of your views for flash[:notice], flash[:alert], flash[:warning] etc...